# Swingworkers can't get GUI variables

Tags: java, progress-bar, swingworker

I have SwingWorker named Worker;

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

               private MainProgramWindow mpw;
               public Worker(MainProgramWindow mpw) {
               this.mpw = mpw;
               }

                public String getStartDate (){
                String inputStringDate = mpw.startDateBox.getText();
                SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                Date inputDate = null;
                try {
                    inputDate = inputFormat.parse(inputStringDate);
                } catch (ParseException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MainProgramWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000");
                String outputStringDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
                return outputStringDate;
              }



              public String getEndDate (){
                 String inputStringDate = mpw.endDateBox.getText();
                 SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                 Date inputDate = null;
                 try {
                     inputDate = inputFormat.parse(inputStringDate);
                 } catch (ParseException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(MainProgramWindow.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,  ex);
                 }

                 SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 23:59:59.999");
                 String outputStringDate = outputFormat.format(inputDate);
                 return outputStringDate;
              }




                @Override
       protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
         //here you make heavy task this is running in another thread not in EDT
          int i = 50;
          setProgress(i);
               //Rest of code.

            ResultSet rs1;
            Statement stmt;
            String query1 = "select date,id,dur from exampletable\n" +
            "where adetdate between '"+getStartDate()+"' and '"+getEndDate()+"'";

           rs1 = stmt.executeQuery(query1);

           //Rest of Code

           while(i <= 100){
           setProgress(i++);
           Thread.sleep(5); // random magic number
           }

        return null;
        }

     }
```

Worker run succesfully and creating excel file in defined location.

My problem is; When i start the Program GUI coming with StartDate Chooser - EndDate Chooser - StartJob Buton. When Buton clicked some progress bar called and progress bar execute this Worker and progress bar start listening.

But Worker always use first GUI appearing values of startdate and enddate. I define two method in Worker for get the actual startdate and enddate values and using them in the String query1.

Why query1 succsefully called but not recognised methods getStartDate() and getEndDate() i dont understand. Any Idea ?

EDIT:
Also i have PbarNEW class for progressbar;

```
package AgentStatGenerator;

    //Imports here    

    public class PbarNEW extends JPanel {

      JProgressBar pbar;

      public PbarNEW() {
        // initialize Progress Bar
        pbar = new JProgressBar();
        // add to JPanel
        add(pbar);

      SwingWorker myWorker = new Worker();
      myWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
      @Override
        public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        switch (event.getPropertyName()) {
        case "progress":
        pbar.setIndeterminate(false);
        pbar.setValue((Integer) event.getNewValue());
        break;
        }
     }
    });
       myWorker.execute(); 
  }

      public static void main(String args[]) {

        final PbarNEW it = new PbarNEW();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Progress Bar Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(it);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


      }
    }
```

When i click Buton in MainProgramWindow (Main GUI) progresbar appearing and start listening of Worker. But SwingWorker myWorker = new Worker(); not working after creating constructor in Worker.

```
private void createExcelButonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
   // TODO add your handling code here:
      String[] arguments = new String[] {"123"};
      PbarNEW.main(arguments); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please edit your question for spelling and grammar. As written it is very difficult to read, making it harder to understand your problem.

As for your problem, are you creating the SwingWorker when an event occurs? For instance, when a button is pressed? If so, you should pass the pertinent values of interest into the SwingWorker via its constructor. I don't see that your SwingWorker even has a constructor. Give it one and allow appropriate parameters to be passed in that will be used set the object's fields.

---

**Edit** regarding changes in your posted code:

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

            MainProgramWindow MPW = new MainProgramWindow();
```

Shoot, you're creating a completely new GUI program inside of your SwingWorker -- **don't do this!**. This object you've created is completely distinct from the one being displayed. Instead pass in constructor parameters as I've suggested. Shoot, you can pass in the current GUI object as a constructor parameter, but don't create a new one in the SwingWorker.

e.g.,

```
public class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

    private MainProgramWindow mpw;

    public Worker(MainProgramWindow mpw) {
      this.mpw = mpw;
    }
```

---

**Edit 2**
For a trivial example of what I mean:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyGui extends JPanel{
   private JTextField textField = new JTextField("Start", 10);
   private JButton button = new JButton("Press Me");

   public MyGui() {
      textField.setEditable(false);
      textField.setFocusable(false);

      button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            MySwingWorker mySwingWorker = new MySwingWorker(MyGui.this); // pass in the GUI
            mySwingWorker.execute();
         }
      });

      add(textField);
      add(button);
   }

   public void setTextFieldText(String text) {
      textField.setText(text);
   }


   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyGui");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new MyGui());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class MySwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
   private static final long SLEEP_TIME = 2 * 1000;
   private MyGui myGui;


   public MySwingWorker(MyGui myGui) {
      this.myGui = myGui; // use the  gui to set a field
   }


   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
      Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
      return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void done() {
      myGui.setTextFieldText("Done!"); // call field's method
   }

}
```

Comment: Sorry for my english. I am not good on grammar. I edit my code above.

Comment: @Lacrymae: see edit to answer. You're shooting yourself in your foot with your code.

Comment: Thanks for your examples. I try them now and update you.

Comment: SwingWorker myWorker = new Worker(); in my progressbar class not working this time. I need it because i start this progress bar in my GUI button actionlistener first.

Comment: @Lacrymae: you're comment above is not clear. Please clarify it for us so we can understand what, if any, are your current problems.

Comment: Oh you are writing fast than me :) I edit my code above you can check it again. I begin read your sample code.

Comment: @Lacrymae: your code shouldn't even compile since you're not passing in the required parameter into your SwingWorker's constructor, Worker.

Comment: I want only press button and start progress bar firstly. Than Progress bar must execute Worker and start listening. Must i change this logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Your worker will use the start date and end date as of the time the instance has been created. This is because your query is created as a member variable, at the time of the object's instantiation.

Move the query construction into the doInBackground and you'll be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edit my code. Adding some instance and move Query blokc inside the doinbackround. But still same issue occured. I choose 02.12.2014 and 02.12.2014 but query executed with 02.12.2014 and 02.15.2014 (these values loaded when program is launched)